# MonoDroid Options Menu Not Showing Up

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Developing for the ZTE Optik tablet which has the floating buttons at the bottom for Back, Home, etc.  The menu button does not appear (apparently) unless the application specifically calls for it.  When I open MyFitnessPal on the tablet, the menu button appears.  However, when adding an Options Menu to my application, the menu button never appears.  OnCreateOptionsMenu never gets called (or at least the breakpoint isn't catching).  I have tried to put the menu on both the TabbedActivity itself as well as just the Activity.

MainMenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/sendLog"
     android:title="Send Log"></item>
</menu>
```

MainMenu.cs

```
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = MenuInflater;
        menuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MainMenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.sendLog:
                var query = new SQLite("Select * From Log", true);
                SqliteDataReader dr = query.dr;
                List<logInfo> logs = new List<logInfo>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    logInfo log = new logInfo
                    {
                        DateTime = dr["DateTime"].ToString(),
                        Call = dr["Call"].ToString(),
                        Activity = dr["Activity"].ToString(),
                        Message = dr["Message"].ToString()
                    };
                    logs.Add(log);
                }

                InventoryApp inst = new InventoryApp();
                inst.sendLog(logs.ToArray());
                return true;
            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't doubt it is something stupid that I'm missing, but if you are going to down vote me, please give a reason!

Comment: up-voted you, I don't know why anyone would down vote this question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that my Minimum Android Version was set to API Level 12.  When I peeled it back to 10, the menu appeared.  Not so sure why this was considered such a terrible question by one nonconstructive member?